# Ubuntu 18 cant reach site

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I have this problem where everything else on internet seems to be reachable, but one single domain is nowhere to be found... making things kinda hard is that this site is my employers site...

cant really post our address but lets say its zzz.com
https://zzz.com
http://zzz.com
zzz.com
https://www.zzz.com

none can be reached from browser...
Network inspector shows single GET query where headers are some random stuff, nothing to do with our headers and response is empty. So i doupt there is really any actual GET query.

i tried to run `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`

which did nothing..
reeboot didnt help either..

Comment: Hard to answer without an actual domain name. Try it on [https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/). But if you normally access the site from your work location, it could be resolved by a DNS server in your employer's IT infrastructure.

Comment: Can you access the site by IP address?